# Stuck on "Encryption unsuccessful"

Tags: twrp, fastboot, xiaomi

I really screwed up and need help now...

I bought a cheap Xiaomi Mi A3 a few days ago for a little project, where I needed a rooted phone (I didn't want to use my main phone for this).
So I tried root the phone with magisk and this tutorial (https://magiskapp.com/root-xiaomi-mi-a3-using-magisk/). Unlocking bootloader worked perfectely fine, so I proceeded with method 1 (using TWRP). I then got a fastboot error which I think has something to do with me using usb3 and not usb2. Since I dont have any Usb2 connectors, I tried to do it with method 2. Somewhere along the way I did a factory reset. Well I did eventually load into TWRP and was able to load the Zip files into TWRP through a MicroSD card, since MTP and "adb push" didn't worked (I didn't got a error message, the files just wouldn't show up on the phone). I then flashed Magisk v22.0 since the others were all "wrong Zip file format". If I try to boot into system now, I always get the "Encryption unsuccessful" error message. I tried to facotry reset, didn't work.
Edit: I can get into TWRP, but reboot to system will always result in "Encryption unsuccessful".

I also tried to flash with MiFlash, but this doesn't work (maybe because of USB 3?)

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this? Is maybe a USB2 hub the key? Since there are no data on this phone I can also just delete everything and reinstall a completely fresh android and start again from the beginning (but since Factory Reset isn't doing this I don't know how to do this).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your phone only has an USB 2.0 port so it doesn't matter how you connect it to the PC, it will always be a USB 2.0 connection.